# What is this soldering mess and how to clean it? And to make this contact proper?

Tags: soldering

I tried to solder 1.5mm<sup>2</sup> cable to a LED COB with Sn at 350°C but it seems that the LED COB has too much thermal momentum and remains too cold for such soldering (the Sn takes the form of a small ball, instead of spreading). I used a Xytronic soldering station LF 399D with a regular conical tip (0.8mm I think).

I started by putting the Sn on the LED and then joining the Cu cable (1.5mm<sup>2</sup>), as recommended by [Er Elektronik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5WTLxoy95A).

As a result, the Sn does not stick to the LED contact and some kind of plastic has appeared:

[image]

[image]

Did I damage the LED COB? Where does this come from? Can I prevent this from happening? How should I clean it (isopropanol / propanol-2)?

Ultimately, how would you recommend to make the electric contact? The current will be 30-40Vdc 8A.

Rather than soldering, I'm thinking about using some spring contact, so the contact is easily reversible and the system more maintainable:

[Spring contacts 1](https://www.compelma.com/products/spring-finger-contacts):
[image: spring contact]

or

[Spring contact 2](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/board-to-board-connectors/spring-finger-contacts.html?tab=pgp-story):
[image: spring contact 2]

Given the current, do you recommend this kind of contact (which one maybe?)?

Comment: You can try to preheat the COB with a hot plate/hot air gun. What kind of soldering station / tip you are using? I think its unlikely that a spring contact will be a good solution for that kind of current.

Comment: It looks like flux residue. It should clean with isopropyl.

Comment: That looks like flux residue. Try cleaning it off with IPA, but you may find it easier to get off with acetone or a proper flux remover.

Comment: @WesleyLee I used a Xytronic soldering station LF 399D with a regular conical tip.

Comment: @WesleyLee The thing is: I don't want to try since it's a 1400 USD LED COB, I need to find and implement the best solution at the first(s) shot. I'm scared to damage the LED with the heat gun.

Comment: @Soleil Practice on cheaper similar things?

Comment: Can you get solder to start on the pad without the wire? It might be easier to get the solder flowing on the pad then attach a tinned wire.

Comment: Add flux and maybe get a larger tip.

Comment: @Soleil the LED COB itself was soldered, so if not done too abruptly, and locally limited, it would be able to sustain close-to-soldering temperatures. If you want to solder onto something with large thermal mass, pre-heating is really the usual and only way. Heat up your COB with a hotplate to 175 °C; then your 80 W station (not that bad, actually!) should be enough to solder this!

Comment: Conical tips usually perform awfully when soldering things with a lot of thermal mass. There's jut not enough contact surface area between the tip and the stuff being soldered. I suggest you use a chisel tip at least 1.2mm wide, but preferably much wider. Pre-heating the board will also make a big difference.

Comment: Bigger tip and preheat the COB.  It is perfectly safe to heat the whole thing to 150C, under normal operation it will be only a little cooler, maybe for months or years at a time.   A few minutes at that temperature is nothing. And yes, practice on a cheap Ebay part first!

Comment: @busfault I tried indeed, and as I mentioned it, the Sn takes the form of a ball, likely because of too low temperature of the LED contact.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Great. Why 175C ?

Comment: electronic solder melts above, it's not much higher than the operating temperature of the LED anyway. In fact, such an expensive COB probably comes with a datasheet or a product line description that tells you something about the solder procedure.

Comment: I suggest that you clean off the old flux and add extra flux from a flux pen or use the gel stuff that comes in a syringe. If this is for home use, you can use tin-lead solder, which melts at a lower temperature than lead-free solder. But still add extra flux. And for the value of the part, buying a can of purpose-made flux remover would be worth it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton what this mean "for home use" ? And why ? And no this is an industrial project. Why using solder with extra flux ? I think we'll stick to the 60% Sn 1mm 190°C melting temp for electronics.

Comment: In addition to what's already been said, cover the wire with solder in advance. Use a big flat tip, crank up the iron to 400-450dgr C temporarily for this job. Use leaded solder if acceptable.

Comment: @Lundin Why in the recommendation video they recommend to stay below 350°C then ? Why 400-450°C ?

Comment: @Soleil 350dgr is the normal setting for professional soldering. Going beyond that will make the tips age badly, plus when you do normal soldering at temperatures that hot, the flux will vaporize too quickly. In this case the metal surface will not get anywhere near those temperatures though. For RoHS solder you roughly need to get the surface to >220dgr and for leaded >180dgr. Anyway, the best advice of all here is to change the tip to a large flat one. Conical tips are only good for small components on PCBs.

Comment: Keep in mind though, that if you are actually soldering LEDs, those can usually not stand heat very well. It's recommended to check the datasheet regarding soldering, set temperature accordingly and ideally only heat them up once.